# Use of TABs in DirectWrite

Tags: c++, directwrite

I am just working my way through DirectWrite in C++ which appears to be solving my demands for having equal layouts in different render targets (screen and printer).

I have closely inspected the HelloWorld sample (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and already learned a lot from that.

The HelloWorld example was even topped (my opinion) by an article from Charles Petzold which was throwing much more light on advanced features of DirectWrite: "Character Formatting Extensions with DirectWrite" (http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2014/01/Character-Formatting-Extensions-with-DirectWrite.html).

But there is still one subject missing in all the documentation and examples I found so far: The documentation about use of TABstops in DirectWrite. All I found so far is a (very) short documentation about setting of "incremental tabs" which does not even mention how the text in each individual tab can be aligned.

Does anybody know about a more in-depth description about TABs in DirectWrite?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That indeed is a very informative article by Petzold (wanted to add a few comments on how to improve some aspects, but comments were closed).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're thinking Word degree of complexity tab stops with individual widths and alignment for each tab - `IDWriteTextLayout` supports uniform tab spacing where each tab is a multiple of a distance set by `SetIncrementalTabStop`. If you need to lay out several unique layouts with distinct distances and alignments, you'll need to create one `IDWriteTextLayout` per column. Tabs are convenient, but they aren't best for tables.